# Anti CSRF Token passed through GET request during File Upload in Vaadin 7 Framework

Tags: get, csrf, vaadin7

Anti CSRF Token is passed through the GET request during File Upload on Vaadin Framework. This is raising a security issue. The security issues says that on implementing this CSRF Token could be used by someone else though GET Request.

According to the [ticket](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8700) in Vaadin issue tracker this has been addressed in Vaadin 8, has this fix been backported to Vaadin 7?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQJOo.png)

Comment: I added details to the question, which makes it legit. This issue has been fixed in Vaadin 7.7.11.